# Getting row data on Interactive Report

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

Morning,

I'm currently using an **Interactive Report** on APEX that contains several columns, some of them being checkboxes that represent if a certain number is present in the table that is being used to fill the report.

For example, **row 1** has a telephone number "99091021", **row 2** a provider, and the following 5 rows are checkboxes that should represent branches in certain areas. If a checkbox is clicked, it means that this number is present in that area.

Now, I'd like to create a dynamic action that inserts that number into that table when I click the checkbox (and it becomes checked), and a delete for when it's also clicked (and becomes unchecked). Problem is, I don't know how to access the rest of the data in the row of the IR to use as a comparison for the delete and insert statements.

Say I try to click the Checkbox 3 on the row where the telephone number is "99091021". A dynamic function would get the data row, then a true action would compare the necessary data to perform either an insert or delete, depending on the state of the checkbox. That's the plan.

I've done something similar before, using **localStorage**, but it didn't quite work, because before I used it on an **interactive grid**. Is there a similar function for interactive reports?

Also, is there a way to check if a checkbox is checked or unchecked in a PL/SQL Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found:

I had a select that got the necessary data for the Interactive Report, but because I kept getting an error of temporary data table being exceeded and always breaking the server, I had to change the checkbox query to something like this:

```
apex_item.checkbox (1, '1_'||a.pk, case when max(decode(b.nr,1,1,null)) is null then '' else 'CHECKED' end) as checkbox1
```

The '1_' part represents me selecting the first checkbox. With the value still there as the selection, I was able to do the following:

```
$s("P165_GET_PK",this.triggeringElement.value)
```

The result would basically be "1_PK_number". With this function I was able to get the value (a.pk) hidden in the checkbox to an Apex item, and then continue using it for my insert and delete statements. It's just a matter of separating the value in it with substring functions and so on.

Now I can delete or insert new data inside that table with a simple click.

I hope it helps in case someone tries doing something similar.

Comment: You may be interested in techniques described here http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html